# Mp3 stream only streams partial file and then breaks every single time, How to fix this?

Tags: python, flask

Here is the code :

```
def stream_track(month):
    def generate():
        with open(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + "potm_" + str(month) + ".mp3", "rb") as audio_stream:
            data = audio_stream.read(1024)
            while data:
                yield data
                data = audio_stream.read(1024)

    persistent_connection = Response(generate(), mimetype='audio/mpeg')
    persistent_connection.headers["Connection".encode("ISO-8859-1")] = "Keep-Alive".encode("ISO-8859-1")
    persistent_connection.headers["Keep-Alive".encode("ISO-8859-1")] = "timeout = 20000 max = 1000".encode("ISO-8859-1")
    return persistent_connection
```

I did it previously without these custom headers but the problem remained, and still no luck.

The error in logs is this :

> IOError: failed to write data

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? The indentation is not correct.

Comment: yes , the first indent got mixed up while pasting code :) , sorry for that

Comment: always in question put full error message (Traceback), not only last part. There are other usefull information, ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: no lines were there in the log , just the ip of the connected client , so I thought I shouldn't post that

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your question; otherwise we don't know where the error is coming from.

Comment: Fixed the indentation